# Does anybody knows a "Morning Brew" like blog for Java?

Tags: java

"The Morning Brew" it's a very well done blogs that each day summarize the best posts for the .Net development platform.

It can be found at http://blog.cwa.me.uk/.

Is there a similar blog for Java? If not is someone interested in doing one? I do not need a series of blog about Java (I've already subscribed) but something that, like the .Net equivalent, posts the most relevant finding of the day.

Comment: [Here's a good one](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A22656+[java]) (follow the link and use "Newest" tab) :-D

Comment: Here's the direct link: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a22656%20java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Took a look at your link, for me something similar to it but in Java World is [TheServerSide.com](http://www.theserverside.com) - "Your Enterprise Java Community"
Another good feed is "[Javalobby - the heart of the Java developer community](http://java.dzone.com/)". In fact I prefer to surf its parent resource http://dzone.com/ - here you can find popular links from different technologies all around the web, and it keeps me up ;)

Answer (score 0):

[The Java Posse](http://javaposse.com/) is an excellent java/news podcast resource, and the "liner" notes for their episodes have detailed links and notes.